# Saving data from SDSS query in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe

I got the data from SDSS by the following query

```
query = """SELECT TOP 20000
        p.psfMag_u, p.psfMag_g, p.psfMag_r, p.psfMag_i, p.psfMag_z, s.class
        FROM PhotoObjAll AS p JOIN specObjAll s ON s.bestobjid = p.objid
        WHERE p.mode = 1 AND s.sciencePrimary = 1 AND p.clean = 1
        ORDER BY s.specobjid ASC
        """
data = SDSS.query_sql(query).to_pandas()
```

> psfMag_g  psfMag_u  psfMag_r  psfMag_i  psfMag_z  class
>
> 19.08541  17.41787  16.59118  16.03507  15.68560  GALAXY

There are 20000 data.
I want to save in *csv* format. How to save the data?